# RxJava return Observable after Observable.zip

Tags: java, observable, rx-java, rx-java2

I have two Observables which are API calls. I want these two to run in parallel and after they both finish I want to call a third observable with the combined result.

For example:

I have an `Observable<List<Place>> getPlaces()` and an `Observable<AdditionalPlaceData> getAdditonalPlaceData()`

My idea was a method that zips them then enriches the places with the additonal data and calls a third observable

I try it like this but the BiFunction of Observable.zip cant return an observable:

```
private Observable<List<Place>> getPlaces(){
    return Observable.zip(getPlaces(), getAdditonalPlaceData(),(places, additonalPlaceData) -> {
            //enrich places with additional data
            return thirdApiCall(places);//This is not allowed
    });
}
```

Is there an other way instead of Observable.zip I dont know to achieve this use case? And I dont want to use flatMap beacuse that would run the two observables in a sequence. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You *can* return an `Observable` from the zipper function, then apply `flatMap` on that to extract the inner values.

Comment: Regarding to my example you mean `return thirdApiCall(places).flatMap()` ?
I cant make it work I think I dont quite understand.

Comment: Observable.zip(..).flatMap(tuple -> thirdApiCall(tuple)) something like this.

Comment: Ah sure, so simpel. Thank you both for the hint!